# How to change username colour in Konsole

Tags: kde, themes, konsole

So my Konsole used to look like this

[image]

but now it's all green and boring

[image]

I don't know what happened and I'm still using the same Breath2 theme created by Manjaro.
The username is not yellow anymore.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, though I suspect you can fix via change to $PS1 (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt) ; but color could have been disabled in terminal, konsole was fixed to single color ....

Comment: Maybe you tweaked your `~/.bashrc`? Do you have any line starting with `PS1=`, even if it's commented out?

Comment: @DK Bose I did bot tweak .bashrc and sorry but I do not have this much knowledge about it.Yes I found a line starting with 'PS1='.This is my .bashrc link https://pastebin.com/1USTbZha

Comment: @guiverc  I looked into the link but I was not able to solve my problem. :(

Comment: I still don't know your OS/release details

Comment: You should **always** provide the information requested. If you have `inxi` installed, it's a simple matter to run `inxi -Sxxz` and to post the output here by use of the [edit] link below your question.

Comment: @guiverc sorry I forgot to mention it.Host: ak-pc  bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.3.0 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.18.4 tk: Qt 5.14.2 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM OS:Ubuntu 19.10 with KDE installed

Comment: Is the `inxi -Sxxz` output edited in any way? It differs in certain significant ways from mine. That is not good 

Comment: @DK Bose No but I will do a fresh reinstall with next release so I guess it will fix a lot of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The operating system and its version have not yet been provided.
- the `~/.bashrc` file linked to in a comment is clearly not the default in Ubuntu or any official flavor.
- you can compare your `~/.bashrc` with the original in `/etc/skel/bashrc`

If the question does involve a supported version of Ubuntu or its official flavors, [Customizing Bash Prompt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CustomizingBashPrompt) should apply.

But I don't need to do this:

> Comment out the default PS1 that's already there by typing a hash mark ( # ) at the beginning of the line, then define your own PS1 and PS2 just below it.

Just adding what I need at the very end of my `~/.bashrc` is sufficient. To get a prompt like what is shown in the image, modify `~/.bashrc` using a plain text editor to have this line at the very end:

```
PS1="\[\033[32m\][\u@\h \w]$ \[\033[0m\]"
```

Save the file and close all open terminals. Now when a terminal is launched, the new prompt is used.

While the link provided above lists the most common components of `PS1`, look at [this](https://vitux.com/how-to-customize-ubuntu-bash-prompt/) or [this](https://www.booleanworld.com/customizing-coloring-bash-prompt/) or just search the internet for much more.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the details I did not know that,I fixed it by replacing .bashrc with an old .bashrc file from my backup thank you :)

Comment: I also find this cool site , it' super easy to create a bashrc with it http://bashrcgenerator.com/